# Woocommerce Shop in shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to build a wordpress shop site for a customer and what I need is a shop in shop system, so that third party can access the shop with an own account to buy for other prices than the usual customer.

Is this possible with Woocommerce. I found some examples inside the docs. but, I’m not absolutely sure of my usecase is possible with Woocommerce.

Comment: Sounds like a wholesale account function that you are after.  Here are some plugins that you can download. https://www.wpmayor.com/top-5-woocommerce-wholesale-plugins/

Comment: It is possible using the custom plugins. Check this out -> https://elextensions.com/plugin/woocommerce-catalog-mode-wholesale-role-based-pricing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly possible. Look for plugins regarding custom user pricing, customer group pricing etc pp, depends on what exactly you need, but it's a pretty straight forward thing.